# mysql - Get distinct values from a Union of 2 sql queries

Tags: mysql

Good Morning,

I am trying to get all the distinct values from a union of two sql queries with this query based from their tag.

```
SELECT t.id, t.tag, bd.owner, bp.param_value as role
FROM baseData db
LEFT JOIN baseParam bp ON bp.`status` = "active" AND bp.param_name = "role" AND bp.base_data_id = bd.id
RIGHT JOIN tag t ON t.base_data_id = bp.base_data_id AND t.`status` = "active"
WHERE bd.`status` = "active" AND bd.application = "template" 
AND (((bp.param_value = "public" OR bp.param_value IS NULL)))
GROUP BY t.tag

UNION

SELECT t.id, t.tag, bd.owner, bp.param_value as role
FROM baseData bd
LEFT JOIN baseParam bp ON bp.`status` = "active" AND bp.param_name = "role" AND bp.base_data_id = bd.id
RIGHT JOIN tag t ON t.base_data_id = bp.base_data_id AND t.`status` = "active"
INNER JOIN resTemplate cr ON cr.base_data_id = bd.id
WHERE bd.`status` = "active" AND bd.application = "template" AND cr.`status` = "active"
AND (((bp.param_value = "private" OR bp.param_value IS NULL))) 
GROUP BY t.tag;
```

Both queries is from the same table, the only difference is their role which is "public" and "private". Private has a consideration from another table as well. This query returns this table

[image]

in this table, as you can see in red box, in the Tag column, Group is repeated. As well as some other Tag names.
How can i change my sql query to filter it so that Tag column is distinct?

Comment: Which of these two rows do you want to include in the result?

Comment: either of the two. All i need is just one of them to be included in the result.

Comment: What exactly database do you use?

Comment: what do you mean by the database i used.?

Comment: Your question tag include `mysql` and `sql-server`. I think you may use one of them.

Comment: im sorry. i only meant mysql. changed it. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this please;)

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT t.id, t.tag, bd.owner, bp.param_value as role
    FROM baseData db
    LEFT JOIN baseParam bp ON bp.`status` = "active" AND bp.param_name = "role" AND bp.base_data_id = bd.id
    RIGHT JOIN tag t ON t.base_data_id = bp.base_data_id AND t.`status` = "active"
    WHERE bd.`status` = "active" AND bd.application = "template" 
    AND (((bp.param_value = "public" OR bp.param_value IS NULL)))

    UNION

    SELECT t.id, t.tag, bd.owner, bp.param_value as role
    FROM baseData bd
    LEFT JOIN baseParam bp ON bp.`status` = "active" AND bp.param_name = "role" AND bp.base_data_id = bd.id
    RIGHT JOIN tag t ON t.base_data_id = bp.base_data_id AND t.`status` = "active"
    INNER JOIN resTemplate cr ON cr.base_data_id = bd.id
    WHERE bd.`status` = "active" AND bd.application = "template" AND cr.`status` = "active"
    AND (((bp.param_value = "private" OR bp.param_value IS NULL)))) TMP
GROUP BY tag;
```

Comment: o. wow. thanks for this. Now i need to translate this query into php yii2.. thanks so much.